# Nhibernate got errors while changing dialect from SQL Server 2008 to 2000

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

My projects are based on ASP.NET MVC4 + SPRING.NET 2.0 + NHIBERNATE 3.3

My developing database is on SQL Server 2008. All works fine in it.

But when I upload published project to production environment using SQé Server 2000, opening any page show errors:

> ROW_NUMBERS not found

and

> Line 1:Syntax Error near '('

and I had changed my database config to `NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Seems you are not using `NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect` in production.

Comment: SQL Server 2000 has been out of Microsoft extended support for two years now. I think there's a case to be made to move to something a little more modern.

Answer (score 0):

update to nhibernate 4.0.3,get solved.But would meet a paging problem see this:
 [Nhibernate 4.0.3 paging with SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579711/nhibernate-4-0-3-paging-with-sql-server-2000)